# C# UTC conversion and Daylight Saving Time in game save

Tags: c#, time, utc, dst

So, I've made a game in which it is required to check the time when saving and loading.

The relevant chunk of loading code:

```
playerData = save.LoadPlayer();

totalSeconds = playerData.totalSeconds;

System.DateTime stamp = System.DateTime.MinValue;

if (!System.DateTime.TryParse(playerData.timeStamp, out stamp)) {
        playerData.timeStamp = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
        stamp = System.DateTime.Parse(playerData.timeStamp);
}

stamp = stamp.ToUniversalTime();

loadStamp = System.DateTime.UtcNow;

long elapsedSeconds = (long)(System.DateTime.UtcNow - stamp).TotalSeconds;

if (elapsedSeconds < 0) {
        ui.Cheater();
}
```

Obviously, all this does is check to see if the currently saved timestamp can be parsed - if so, we make sure it's UTC, if not, we set the stamp to the current time and continue. If the elapsed time between the loaded timestamp and current time is negative, we know the player has messed with their clock to exploit the system.

The potential problem arises when the clocks move an hour back for DST.

This is the relevant code in the save function, if it matters:

```
if (loadStamp == System.DateTime.MinValue) {
    loadStamp = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
}

playerData.timeStamp = loadStamp.AddSeconds(sessionSeconds).ToString("o");
```

My question is:

Will this  currently used method potentially cause any problems when the clocks move back and falsely deem players cheaters?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Forgot to add that it seems to not cause any problems on the computer when the time is set to when the clocks move back, but the game is mobile. Again, if that matters at all. Not quite sure. I've not done much with time-based rewards and stuff in games thus far.

Comment: How would DST matter at all if you are converting to UTC? That's the entire point of using UTC instead of local time

Comment: That was sort of the point. Maybe I'm just being paranoid. I'm in no way a coding noob, I've been doing this for a needlessly long time. A player of my game just sent me an email that concerned me that this might be a flaw, citing that the clocks just moved back in Brazil where he's from. Although, he could have actually just cheated and lied about it.

Comment: Maybe look into [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx).  It is used to represent a point in time, regardless of local time or daylight savings, and has methods to convert back and forth from local time.

Comment: So, do you think this might actually be a legitimate issue? I mean, is it even possible that a clock move would effect any of the calculations I'm doing here? I've read a bit about that, I was just unsure if it was necessary for my purposes here.

Comment: No, it's not a real issue. You might want to add some few milliseconds of offset as acceptable though. Don't use `TotalSeconds` by the way, use `TotalMilliseconds`

Comment: I can't spot any situation in which this code would yield an incorrect result.  However, I would recommend using UTC throughout, and specify `DateTimeKind.Utc` where required.  For example, [DateTime.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Returns) will be taking your RoundTrip value, converting it into Local time, then you're converting it straight back to Utc.

Comment: FWIW, Daylight Savings did just end in [Brazil](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia).  Makes it less likely that the player is cheating.

Comment: Right, and that's why I decided to post here after testing. Was hoping someone with more experience using DateTime could point out a flaw with what I'm doing. I mean, I tested it on my computer by changing my time zone to one in Brazil, setting my time to 11:59 PM of the 17th, saving the game, letting it progress one minute and going back in the game, and received no cheating notice. This makes me think the DST wasn't the issue. I'm pretty confused as to what may have caused this to happen - or, again - he could've just lied about it and used that as a convenient excuse.

Comment: Camilo, that would most likely be ideal. I just didn't need millisecond accuracy. I'll probably change it anyway.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when using UTC and local time stamps is that a UTC time stamp (with the time zone info in it) is converted to local time when it gets parsed. Stupid, but that’s what .Net does.

Comment: I've voted to close this as an off-topic question. The question itself, and the answer given and accepted are both non-verifiable.

Comment: If you can re-work the question to better describe the desired behavior and the problem, then it might be an answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**  I have significantly updated this answer in respect of comments made by @theMayer and the fact that while I was wrong, it may have highlighted a bigger issue.

---

I believe there is an issue here in the fact that the code is reading the UTC time in, converting it to local time, then converting it back to UTC.

The save routine records the value of `loadStamp` expressed with the Round Trip format specifier `o`, and as `loadStamp` is always set from `DateTime.UtcNow`, the value stored in the file will always be a UTC time with a trailing "Z" indicating UTC time.

For example:

> 2018-02-18T01:30:00.0000000Z  ( = 2018-02-17T23:30:00 in UTC-02:00 )

The issue was reported in the [Brazil](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia) time zone, with a UTC offset of UTC-02:00 (BRST) until 2018-02-18T02:00:00Z and a UTC offset of UTC-03:00 (BRT) after.

The code reaches this line:

```
if (!System.DateTime.TryParse(playerData.timeStamp, out stamp)) {
```

[DateTime.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) (which uses the same rules as [DateTime.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Returns)) will encounter this string.  It will then convert the UTC time into a local time, and set `stamp` to equal:

> 2018-02-17T23:30:00  DateTimeKind.Local

The code then reaches:

```
stamp = stamp.ToUniversalTime();
```

At this point, `stamp` *should* represent an Ambiguous time, i.e. one that exists as a valid BRST and a valid BRT time, and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) states:

> If the date and time instance value is an ambiguous time, this method assumes that it is a standard time. (An ambiguous time is one that can map either to a standard time or to a daylight saving time in the local time zone)

This means that .NET *could* be changing the UTC value of any ambiguous DateTime values that are converted to Local time and back again.

*Although the documentation states this clearly, I have been unable to reproduce this behaviour in the Brazilian time zone.  I am still investigating this.*

---

My approach to this type of issue is to use the `DateTimeOffset` type instead of `DateTime`.  It represents a point-in-time that is irrelevant of local time, time zones, or Daylight Savings.

An alternative approach to closing this hole would be to change:

```
if (!System.DateTime.TryParse(playerData.timeStamp, out stamp)) {
    playerData.timeStamp = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
    stamp = System.DateTime.Parse(playerData.timeStamp);
}
stamp = stamp.ToUniversalTime();
```

to

```
if (!System.DateTime.TryParse(playerData.timeStamp, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out stamp)) {
    stamp = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
    playerData.timeStamp = stamp.ToString("o");
}
```

Again assuming that the saved `playerData.timeStamp` will always be from a UTC date and therefore be in "Z" timezone, adding the `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` should mean it gets parsed straight into `DateTimeKind.Utc` and not converted into Local time as `DateTimeKind.Local`.  It also eliminates the need to call `ToUniversalTime()` on it to convert it back.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think there are greater odds of a meteor wiping out all life on Earth tomorrow than this scenario happening.

Comment: @theMayer True, but as with all thread-safety issues (which is ultimately what this is), it's better to make the code bullet-proof.  Sometimes things happen which make infinitesimal chances much more likely, such as a .NET framework background re-compilation on a slow system making .NET take seconds per line of code, or deploying Network Time Synchronisation suddenly fixes a local clock difference between two servers so their scheduled tasks start competing for network resources more.  Something happened to get that bug report, and I prefer to be able to be certain that the code is correct.

Comment: The first iteration is up to ~600k players worldwide, and if this iteration hits those numbers, we're talking about maybe 5-10k DAU saving every 30 seconds with an average play time of ~3,000 seconds a player per day. So, as you could imagine, there's a lot of chances for Earth to get struck by that meteor, but the chances are still pretty small. Given that the game was launched very recently and only has 1k players, the chances of this happening already are incredibly small. Thank you for the detailed response and solution. I appreciate all the help, guys.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that comment late at night. It turns out that the whole premise is wrong to begin with. `ToUniversalTime()` uses the time stamp that is called upon, not the current time, to figure out what UTC is for the given local time. This is static and not modified when the time changes from DST to regular (as that point in time is also fixed).

Comment: So there actually is no chance of this scenario playing out in reality?

Comment: Just double-checking myself.  @theMayer can you cite a source?

Comment: From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx): "The conversion also takes into account the daylight saving time rule that applies to the time represented by the current DateTime object."

Comment: I used to write code that dealt with multiple local time zones and converted stuff to UTC and back. I'm pretty well-versed in the pitfalls of .NET date time objects.

Comment: @theMayer I disagree with your assessment.  `DateTime` does not store any Time Zone or UTC Offset information (that is what `DateTimeOffset` is for).  If I call `DateTime.Now` at `2018-02-18T01:30:00Z` in Brazil (UTC-02:00), the value will be `2018-02-17T23:30:00 DateTimeKind.Local`.  If I call it again at `2018-02-18T02:30:00Z` in Brazil (UTC-3), the value will be exactly the same.  At this point, the two objects are identical and cannot be converted back to UTC, the time zone information has been lost.  I'm more than happy to change or retract my answer if it's wrong, but I don't see it.

Comment: You are correct that DateTime does not contain time zone information. The purpose of DateTime is to represent a date and time irrespective of the time zone. Therefore, so long as your time zone of reference is consistent between DateTimes, there will be no conflict. Comparing a UTC DateTime to a local DateTime will result in an inequality. Converting a local DateTime to a UTC will always be deterministic. Your argument is that that conversion is different depending on the time of day that the conversion is called. That is incorrect. The conversion depends only on the subject DateTime.

Comment: What I ended up doing in my case, to avoid this matter altogether, was to create a UnixEpochTime which uses seconds since 1970 and is by-definition UTC. There was no ambiguity with this method.

Comment: @M.W. Could you please review this and unaccept this answer.  In clarifying my own misunderstandings with the help of theMayer, I have discovered some odd behaviour which I am still investigating.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On the surface, there does not appear to be anything *obviously* wrong with this code.

When doing `DateTime` comparison operations, it is important to ensure that the time zone of the compared `DateTime`'s are consistent. The framework only compares the values of the instances, irrespective of whatever time zone you think they are in. It is up to you to ensure consistent time zones between `DateTime` instances. It looks like that is being done in this case, as times are converted from local to UTC prior to being compared with other UTC times:

```
stamp = stamp.ToUniversalTime();
elapsedSeconds = (long)(System.DateTime.UtcNow - stamp).TotalSeconds;
```

**Some Caveats**

One item that often trips people up is that the time value is repeatedly queried (each call to `DateTime.UtcNow`) - which *could* result in different values each time. However, the difference would be infinitesimal, and most of the time zero as this code will execute faster than the [resolution of the processor clock](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime/).

Another fact, which I brought up in the comments, the ["Round Trip Format Specifier"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip) used to write the `DateTime` to string is intended to preserve time zone information - in this case, it *should* add a "Z" to the time to denote UTC. Upon conversion back (via `TryParse`), **the parser will convert this time from the UTC to a local time *if the Z is present.*** This can be a significant gotcha as it results in an actual `DateTime`value that is different from the one serialized to the string, and in a way is contrary to every other way that the .NET framework handles `DateTime`'s (which is to ignore time zone info).  If you have a case where the "Z" is not present in the incoming string, but the string is otherwise UTC, then you have a problem there because it will be comparing a UTC time whose value has been adjusted a second time (thus making it the time of UTC +2).

It should also be noted that in .Net 1.1, `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` is NOT an [idempotent function](https://www.google.com/search?q=idempotent+function&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b). It will offset the `DateTime` instance by the difference in time zone between the local time zone and UTC each time it is called. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.71).aspx):

> This method assumes that the current DateTime holds the local time value, and not a UTC time. Therefore, each time it is run, the current method performs the necessary modifications on the DateTime to derive the UTC time, whether the current DateTime holds the local time or not.

Programs using a later version of the framework may or may not have to worry about this, depending on usage.

Comment: "It should also be noted that DateTime.ToUniversalTime() is NOT an idempotent function".  This is incorrect since the behaviour was changed in .NETv2, although you reference the .NETv1.1 documentation.  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)  "Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, the value returned by the ToUniversalTime method is determined by the Kind property of the current DateTime object.  ... Kind = Utc, Results = No conversion is performed."

Comment: Good catch. In most cases, Kind is unspecified however. In any case, the way .Net handles `DateTime`'s is stupid at best, and it is best not to use conversion functions unless you know with absolute certainty that it is appropriate. In this case, that assumption is tenuous as there is an external factor (the file) involved.

Comment: Yeah, "the way .Net handles DateTime's is stupid at best".  I'm finding that.  I'm actually changing the wrong parts of my answer based on your comments.  I'm still sure there's a bug, but not the one I suggested.  At present I'm flat out struggling to explain the behaviour I'm seeing from `DateTime`.  I might post a question of my own shortly :P

Comment: The fact that only one person is complaining leads me to believe that it's a user problem :)

Comment: If you want me to look at it, paste it here once you've asked.